# SAS Enterprise Miner - Unable to launch the application (on Mac)

Tags: sas, data-mining, data-science, data-analysis, dm

I downloaded SAS Enterprise Miner.jnlp (version 14.3) and it works **only right after the download**.  If I close the application for a couple of hours (eg.: try to open it again in the next day), the error “Unable to launch the application” appers and the application doesn't open anymore. If I download again, it does work (but again, after some hours closed, will rise the same error).

I've already tried these JDK versions: 1.8.0_112-b16, 1.8.0.161 and jdk 1.8.0.181. (I've also tried to clean the Java cache for applications).

Any idea? I have a **MacOS High Sierra, version 10.13.6.**

Here's the details of the error:

**Exception:**

```
com.sas.svcs.security.authentication.client.TicketCreationException: Unable to acquire ticket: <404 Not Found,{Date=[Sun, 30 Sep 2018 18:41:23 GMT], Server=[Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)], X-Frame-Options=[SAMEORIGIN], X-Content-Type-Options=[nosniff], X-UA-Compatible=[IE=edge], Content-Length=[0], Keep-Alive=[timeout=5, max=100], Connection=[Keep-Alive]}>
    at com.sas.svcs.security.authentication.client.AuthenticationClient.acquireTicket(AuthenticationClient.java:303)
(…)
```

**Launch File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="https://odamid.oda.sas.com/SASEnterpriseMinerJWS/">
  <information>
    <title>SAS Enterprise Miner 14.3</title>
    <vendor>SAS Institute, Inc.</vendor>
    <homepage href="/SASEnterpriseMinerJWS" />
    <description>SAS Enterprise Miner Java Web Start application</description>
    <description kind="short">SAS Enterprise Miner JWS</description>
    <icon href="images/emlogo.gif" />
    <icon href="images/saslogo.gif" kind="splash" />
  </information>
  <security>
    <all-permissions />
  </security>
  <resources>
    <j2se version="1.6+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" max-heap-size="1024m" />
(…)
```

Comment: Sadly EM isn't really designed to work with Macs. If you can run it on a PC I think it's more stable but their newer product VDMML is more stable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SAS Enterprise Miner provided by SAS® OnDemand for Academics is a On-Cloud application, witch uses The downloaded JNLP to launch it on-client (and in turn (probably) has a session control that expires under some conditions).

Actually by reading the [definition of JNLP](http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/j2ee101302/developing_webstart_applications/ui_pjwscreating.html) is clear that actually it isn't an application, but only a launching protocol:

"You use the Java Web Start Wizard to create the XML-based JNLP (Java Network Launching Protocol) definition file that the Java Web Start software uses to download and run Java applications and applets on client machines."

In summary, every time you want to launch it on your machine, you need an updated launcher, thus clink on the [SAS® Enterprise Miner™](https://odamid.oda.sas.com/SASODAControlCenter/) link to download a new JNLP and launch a new session of the on-cloud application.

Comment: I have an open miner project and am trying to save a diagram to a location but am getting this same error. So it looks like I have to open a new JNLP. As a uni student this is a joke considering this is supposed to be "industry leading" analytics software. Anyway, how do I not lose my miner project? It seems the project is mirrored in SASStudio. What do I need to do to make sure this project+diagram is saved somewhere? SAS Miner won't let me save the diagram to any location because of this error. Does SAS Studio have me covered? Thanks.